# Reseasoning Cast Iron

Tags: cast-iron

I just stumbled on the site while searching for an answer. I'm hoping one of you can provide an answer.

I bought a brand new pan that is factory seasoned and I didn't strip it off.

I used vegetable oil and it came out uneven, sticky spots, and does not have the wonderful non-stick surface I would like. I tried it about 2 more times and same result. I've since picked at it, scraped bits off, noticed what looked brownish/blackish, washed it, cooked bacon in it, scrubbed it with a steelo (stainless steel scrubber). Honestly can't tell if it's rust. It's brand new with factory season. I'm lost.

I'm about to try flaxseed oil. Can I can put this different oil/seasonings right over my current seasonings or do I have to strip it all off with chemicals and start all over?

Comment: Partially cooked seasoning is relatively smooth and might even be shiny ... rust will be dull, dry and powdery

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/91173/67

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to season a cast iron skillet?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/641/whats-the-best-way-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet)