# Seasoning a wok in the wrong way?

Tags: seasoning-pans, wok

I've just bought a wok recently and seasoned it. The only thing i realized at the end is that it never became blue, it's just a dark brown color. Is there a possibility to season it wrong? I've added a few layers of coat with oil, however i have no clue if this can be a health issue on the long run or not. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't tell us exactly what you did, so we can't tell you if any of it was wrong. In the meantime, see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/85/42066 and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/71276/42066

Answer (score -1):

You are probably not using the right oil and/or heating it hot enough.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.